# Trying to open service master key in powershell but failed

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I recently add script to log ship manually in sql server 2014 via powershell.

so I can read header without creating temp table!
and I recently try to add password support for this script.
here is the scripts

```
$masterdb=$server.databases["master"];
$masterkey = New-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.MasterKey -argumentlist $masterdb;        
$masterkey.Import($mkeyinfo.filefullname,$mkeyinfo.password,$mkeyinfo.password,$true);

$bdi=new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem') ($FileFullName, 'File');
$restore.Devices.Add($bdi);
$restoreHeaders=$restore.ReadBackupHeader($server);
```

I already restored certificate with private key.So before I read header info of backup All i need is just open the service masterkey with password.
But it always fail with message like following...

masterkey 'Microsoft.SqlServer.management.smo.objectkeybase' fail...

I don't see any detail information of fail.. somebody helps!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the Master Key, but ReadBackupHeader just runs a command, and is the same as `invoke-sqlcmd "RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM  DISK = N'C:\xxxx\xxxx.bak' WITH  NOUNLOAD"`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you! I Tried to Backup Master key from Source Server and restore it into destination server so I can restore the transaction log backup file..

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft But readbackupheader is equal as invoke-sqlcmd gives me an key to the answer!!! Thank You Very much!